# Get the Service Bus SharedAccessKey Programatically Using Bicep

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I am using bicep to create azure resources.  One of these resources is a service bus and this is defined as follows:

```
resource service_bus 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces@2021-01-01-preview' = {
  name: '${service_bus_name}${uniqueString(service_bus_name)}'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard'
    tier: 'Standard'
  }
  properties: {}
}
```

I then want to use this service bus in another resource and this is what I currently have for the connection string:

```
name: 'AzureWebJobsServiceBus'
value: 'Endpoint=sb://${service_bus.name}.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=<hardcoded_key>'
```

How can I avoid the hard coded key.  I tried using listKeys like this:

```
SharedAccessKey=${listKeys(service_bus.id, service_bus.apiVersion).value[0].primaryKey}
```

But this does not work, and variations on this also fail.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, `listKeys` bicep function for Service Bus maps to [`Namespaces - Authorization Rules - List Keys`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/stable/namespaces-authorization-rules/list-keys).

You will need to include `AuthorizationRules/{authorizationRuleName}` in your `listKeys` method call. For `authorizationRuleName` you can make use of `RootManageSharedAccessKey`.

I'm not sure if this would work (my first time playing around with bicep), but you can give it a try:

```
var listKeysEndpoint = '${service_bus.id}/AuthorizationRules/RootManageSharedAccessKey'
SharedAccessKey=${listKeys(listKeysEndpoint, service_bus.apiVersion).primaryKey}
```

Comment: Excellent Gaurav, just needed a minor tweak otherwise worked like a charm.  Final code:

`var endpoint = '${service_bus.id}/AuthorizationRules/RootManageSharedAccessKey'`
`...`
`value: 'Endpoint=sb://${service_bus.name}.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=${listKeys(endpoint, service_bus.apiVersion).primaryKey}'`

Answer (score 7):

You can also try:

```
var serviceBusEndpoint = '${service_bus.id}/AuthorizationRules/RootManageSharedAccessKey'
var serviceBusConnectionString = listKeys(serviceBusEndpoint, service_bus.apiVersion).primaryConnectionString
```

to get the connection string for the Service Bus.